# How to use a query-results in the same Select statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my select statement I calculate some values and then need to calculate a new value based on the results of the already calculated values. How can this be archived without using a temp table?

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN [Customer] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE NULL END AS Ver_a              
    , CASE WHEN [Service] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE NULL END AS Ver_b             
    , CASE WHEN [Productavailability] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE NULL END AS Ver_c    
    , (SUM(Ver_a, Ver_b, Ver_c)/3) AS Identity_Ver
FROM x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a sub-query/derived table:

```
SELECT
    Ver_a             
    , Ver_b                
    , Ver_c
    , (coalesce(Ver_a,0) + coalesce(Ver_b,0) + coalesce(Ver_c,0))/3 AS Identity_Ver
FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN [Customer] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE NULL END AS Ver_a             
      , CASE WHEN [Service] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE NULL END AS Ver_b                
      , CASE WHEN [Productavailability] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE NULL END AS Ver_c
    FROM x
) x
```

Note 1: as you are not grouping you don't need the `sum` function, just the sum operator (`+`) - and the [sum function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't take a comma separated list of values either.

Note 2: your sum won't work without using the `coalesce` function as you are returning null from the case expressions.

Comment: How do you safely integrate this sub-query into the larger Select statement?  So if I have Select ID, Date..Select Ver_a ..From (select case .. as Ver_a from x)x -Would I have to put ID, Date into the Select Ver_a .. and the select case .. as Ver_a .. or how can I integrate this?

Comment: @Anna in this form of sub-query you select all the columns you need from the base table within the sub-query. Also you can nest sub-querys as many levels as you need. An alternative form is also a CTE... its the same thing, just different syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you cannot do `sum(var1, var2, var3)`.

The answer to your question, as stated, seems to be the code at the end.

BUT, I have to ask: what do you want to accomplish? Your approach does make sense to me :-(

```
SELECT
    Sum(
        CASE WHEN [customer]            = '173220000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [service]             = '173220000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [productavailability] = '173220000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) / 3 AS Identity_Ver 
FROM x
```